# How do you view/list projects within a workspace within Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm brand new to Eclipse (learning Python).  I'm really confused about the terminology within Eclipse.  I had previously created a "hello world" project and exited Eclipse.  I've restarted Eclipse, but how do I list all of the projects in the current workspace?  Is there a way to do that?  If not how do I open a project?  I tried using "Import" but it said the project was already in the workspace.  What ever happened to say an option to "Open Project..."?  This seems way overly complicated.  I guess other questions I have are:

How do you determine the currently set "workspace"?
How do you see what workspaces are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects for the current workspace are shown in the "Package Explorer" view, which displays them as in a "Windows Explorer" fashion. Using this view you can open/close and manage your projects for a given workspace. If you currently don't have Package Explorer open, you can go to Window->Show View->Package Explorer. If package explorer is not an option there just select "Other..." and look under General.

Note that projects are not shared across workspaces, so if you create a new workspace or switch to a different one you won't see the other one's projects.